# Error Loading JSON from configuration file using ConfigParser

Tags: python, json, configparser

I have this configuration file

```
[section1]
namespace = {'pro1':'http://pro1/go','pro2':'http://pro2/go','pro3':'http://pro3/go'}
```

Reading the file with ConfigParser I got:

```
>>> from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
>>> Config = ConfigParser()
>>> Config.read("myfile.ini")
>>> name = Config.get("section1", "namespace")
>>> name
"{'pro1':'http://pro1/go','pro2':'http://pro2/go','pro3':'http://pro3/go'}"
```

To convert the string to dict/json:

```
>>> import json
>>> namespace = json.loads(name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Json keys and values must be put inside double quotes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not valid JSON; unlike Python dicts, JSON is very strict - you always need to use double quotes.

```
namespace = {"pro1":"http://pro1/go","pro2":"http://pro2/go","pro3":"http://pro3/go"}
```